# Yii custom model errors

Tags: php, yii

I am saving a model instance performing some actions in "beforeSave" model function.
I want to add some errors/messages to the model and then to get them in the controller and show to the user.
As far I have two ideas of how to implement this:

- Use a dummy attribute with ActiveRecord function `"addError": $this->addError("dummy"=>"my message");`    It is not the best way to do it as I'll have to invent new dummy attributes.
- Add a new property "custom_errors" to the model and function "addCustomErrors"

Maybe there is a built-in way to do it or an extension?
Anyway how can I do it?

Comment: You want to add error messages inside `beforeSave`? That's not a good idea, why don't you do that while validating?

Comment: cause for instance I upload a file and have to check it is uploaded to the server, or I perform other actions like clearing cache and so on that have nothing to do with the validation

Comment: All of this should have completed successfully *before* you call `save` though...

Comment: I am not sure. I am uploading a file with swfuploader and just populate the "file" field in the form, clearing cache is done after the file is saved in fact, anyway I want to tell the user the action was performed. Some fields of the record are generated based on other information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the addError() but there's no need to make up fake attributes. If an error doesn't relate to **anything** on the model itself then your doing something wrong :p

So in your case it would be something like:

```
 $this->addError('file', 'Something happened I wasn\'t pleased with');
```

If there are any other errors on the `file` attribute they'll acumlate so you don't need to worry about overwriting.

Comment: just one question. if I want to pass a message that is not an error. let's say I want to replace the uploaded file and want to tell the user that it has been replaced. If I make it in addError, I am not sure the model will be saved, as it has an error.

Comment: Add error shouldn't effect the saving of the model. as long as it validates it should save

Comment: I need to validate that the record is not created at a wrong time of the day. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem here. Simply use addError() http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#addError-detail. The model is kept even after invoking `save()` on it, so you could just do something like

```
yourController()
{
   do_something();
   do_something();
   $model->save();
   $errors[]=do_what_you_have_to_do_to_define_the_errors_which_will_be_added();
   $model->addError(attribute, $errors);
   $this->render(viewWhereTheErrorWillBeDisplayed, $model);
}
```

Comment: The question is how to add errors without any attribute